# hp EliteBook 8470p Intel HD 4000 graphic card MP4 video 1080p and some game are not working properly

Tags: graphics-card

I have hp EliteBook 8470p i5-3320m, 8GB ram, Intel HD 4000 graphic card.

I am trying to play MP4 video 1080p and some are not working properly .

1. How can I check if I have discrete graphics card of AMD Radeon 7570M or not?

   It is not shown in the BIOS or the Windows device manager.
2. It is possible to upgrade discrete graphic card?
3. Is there any option to change share memory of Intel graphic card 4000?
4. If I upgrade 8GB ram to 16GB ram will it improve  graphics quality or not?

Comment: **If i upgrade 8GB ram to 16GB ram it will be improve graphics quality or not ?** - It will not.  You have not even proven your system performance is because of your memory, increasing you rmemory, will NOT increase or decrease your graphical computation performance.

Answer (score 1):

The Elitebook 8470p/8570p came with either AMD Radeon or Intel graphics, not both, you have one or the other unlike some notebooks who contain both and use a switchable graphics technology.

1. Intel drivers are loaded, they recognize the chipset as Intel 4000. That is what you have
2. No, it is not possible to "upgrade" the graphics. The graphics subsystem is built into the mainboard. If you want to upgrade it, you need to swap out the main board which would likely be more work and money than replacing the entire machine.
3. No, for Intel 3000/4000 based graphics the system allocates memory automatically and you cannot statically assign memory available to the Intel graphics system like you can on newer chipsets.
4. Most likely not, especially since 8GB should allow for the maximum amount of memory to be allocated to the graphics system. If you had 2GB of RAM then a jump to 8 or 16 would likely help, but going from 8 to 16 likely won't make much difference in graphics performance.

Comment: Typically the largest amount memory dedecated to the an Intel iGPU is 2GB.  I have my doubts its even 1GB due to the hardware described.